# Supremum and union

Tags: real-analysis

$A_i \subset \mathbb{R}, i \in \mathbb{N}$

Is $$ \sup \{\sup A_i, i \in \mathbb N\} = \sup (\cup_i A_i)?$$
Thanks.

Comment: You mean to say: $$\displaystyle \cup_i \sup A_i = \sup \cup_i A_i?$$ If this is what you mean, note the left hand sight is a set while the right hand side is a number...

Comment: Both sides are numbers. Edited.

Comment: your edit makes it clearer, thanks

Comment: Yes, this identity holds indeed. This is because $A_i \subset \bigcup_j A_j$ for all $i$ implies $\sup A_i \leq \sup \bigcup_j A_j$ for all $i$ on the one hand. And $x \in \bigcup_j A_j \implies \exists i : x \in A_i \implies \exists i : x \leqslant \sup A_i$ on the other hand.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Denote $A=\bigcup A_{i}$. Then for every $i$ we have $\sup A_{i}\leq\sup A$
as a consequence of $A_{i}\subseteq A$ so that $\sup\sup A_{i}\leq\sup A$.

Conversely if $x<\sup A$ then $x<a$ is true for some $a\in A$. Let's say that $a\in A_{i_{0}}$.

Then $x<a\leq\sup A_{i_{0}}\leq\sup\sup A_{i}$ and
since this is true for *every* $x<\sup A$ we are allowed to conclude
that $\sup A\leq\sup\sup A_{i}$.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, since $\cup_i A_i \supset A_i$, we have $$\sup\cup_i A_i \geq  \sup A_i$$
then take $\sup$ again on rhs, we have $$\sup\cup_i A_i \geq  \sup\{\sup A_i, i \in \mathbb{N}\} \tag 1$$

To prove the equality, take any $\epsilon >0$, then by definition,  $\exists x \in \cup_i A_i$ such that $$x + \epsilon > \sup\cup_i A_i$$

Suppose $x \in A_{i_0}$, then $$\sup A_{i_0} + \epsilon \geq x + \epsilon > \sup\cup_i A_i $$

which means for any $\epsilon >0$, we can find one element in $\{\sup A_i, i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ such that this element plus $\epsilon$ is greater than $ \sup\cup_i A_i$. Combined with $(1)$, we've proven $$\sup\cup_i A_i = \sup\{\sup A_i, i \in \mathbb{N}\} $$

Answer (score 2):

Every upper bound of $\bigcup A_i$ is an upper bound of $\{\sup A_i, i\in\Bbb N\}$. Indeed, if some $x$ is an upper bound of every $A_i$, then $x\geq \sup A_i$ for all $i$

Conversely, every upper bound $x$ of $\{\sup A_i, i\in\Bbb N\}$ is an upper bound of each $A_i$, that is, it is greater than or equal to every element of every $A_i$. Then $x$ is an upper bound of $\bigcup A_i$.

But note that for all of this makes sense, the set $\bigcup A_i$ must be upper bounded (unless you consider that the sup of a non bounded set is $\infty$). Note also that the set of indexes can be uncountable. The fact that the set of indexes is $\Bbb N$ is not used anywhere.